# Applying cap on only one end of a stroked line in Android

Tags: drawing, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose, stroke

Is it possible to apply a cap to only one of the two ends of a stroke while drawing in a Compose Canvas DrawScope context?

Comment: Hi, I actually ended up with a different solution but I will accept your answer for sure, I actually forgot, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in solution.

I could not find a solution for `android.graphics.Canvas` either: if you know how to do it in plain android canvas, you can use it in compose c with `drawIntoCanvas`.

The only approach I can think of is to draw the caps on top:

```kotlin
fun DrawScope.drawLine(
    color: Color,
    start: Offset,
    end: Offset,
    strokeWidth: Float = Stroke.HairlineWidth,
    startCap: StrokeCap,
    endCap: StrokeCap,
) {
    drawLine(
        color = color,
        start = start,
        end = end,
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        cap = StrokeCap.Butt,
    )
    listOf(
        Triple(start, end, startCap),
        Triple(end, start, endCap),
    ).forEach {
        drawCap(
            color = color,
            start = it.first,
            end = it.second,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
            cap = it.third
        )
    }
}

private fun DrawScope.drawCap(
    color: Color,
    start: Offset,
    end: Offset,
    strokeWidth: Float = Stroke.HairlineWidth,
    cap: StrokeCap,
) {
    when (cap) {
        StrokeCap.Butt -> Unit
        StrokeCap.Round -> {
            drawCircle(color, center = start, radius = strokeWidth / 2)
        }
        StrokeCap.Square -> {
            val offset = Offset(strokeWidth / 2, strokeWidth / 2)
            val size = Size(strokeWidth, strokeWidth)

            rotateRad(
                radians = (end - start).run { atan2(x, y) },
                pivot = start
            ) {
                drawRect(color, topLeft = start - offset, size = size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calculating angle in case for a line in `StrokeCap.Square` is pretty simple, but if you need this for curves the solution may not be that easy.

But in you only need to support `StrokeCap.Round` knowing the start/end points and stroke width will be enough.